# UEFN (Unreal editor for fortnite) Transparent cube becoming opaque when i destroy a build close to it on Fortnite

Tags: unreal-engine5

As you can see on the screens, if i build right next to a transparent cube then destroy the build, it is no longer transparent. Do you have an idea of the reason ?

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvceE.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5LQy.png)

I tried to change all settings of the cube (hlod, collision, damages deactivated..) and didn't find anything.